# Framing a question on "results" of a malarial infection ("Enlargement of the spleen and liver and blockage of capillaries in the brain")

Tags: vocabulary

> What are the **results** of the infection of malaria?

In the question sentence, is the use of "the results" correct? Can I use "the effects" instead of "the results"? If the answer to the question is :

> Enlargement of the spleen and liver and blockage of capillaries in the brain.

I would like to know how to ask the question.

Answer (score 2):

> Enlargement of the spleen and liver and blockage of capillaries in the brain.

If the answer were as the above, I would pose the question thus:

> What are the **effects** of the infection of malaria?
>   *a simpler variant*: What are the **effects** of malaria on the body?

Why? Because the word "**results**" is too like "**outcomes**" to my taste, and the possible outcomes of an infection usually include: death, recovery, partial recovery etc.

Effects are changes that may subside with treatment or with the passage of time. The spleen and liver might gradually decrease in size, the capillaries might de-clog.

Bear in mind that I'm not a native speaker. Wait for some natives to chime in.

### Usage Examples

> What are the **effects of malaria** on the body? - Malaria has a number of **effects** on the body.  (from *[Malaria.com](http://www.malaria.com/questions/malaria-effects-body)*)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use "[symptom](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/symptom)" which means:

> A ***physical or mental feature*** which is regarded as ***indicating a
>   condition of disease***, particularly such a feature that is apparent to
>   the patient: dental problems may be a symptom of other illness.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

You could visit this [site](http://www.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/malaria-symptoms) which is self-explanatory.

> What are the ***symptoms*** of malaria?

Note:

1. You don't necessarily need to use "the infection of malaria". Malaria is one of many infectious diseases.
2. Results could be consequences or outcomes. Results of malaria could be death, paralysis, and loss of sight, etc. They are not symptoms that indicate a condition of disease.