# Which is correct, result or effect?

Tags: usage

> What is the result/effect of the lack of a strong gravitational pull on the moon?

In this question, which is correct, result or effect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Framing a question on “results” of a malarial infection (“Enlargement of the spleen and liver and blockage of capillaries in the brain”)](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/73862/3281).

Comment: Another note: the sentence is ambiguous. Usually we would write "a/the result of something" or "an/the effect of something on someone/something". The way the sentence is written is unclear whether it's about what happens to someone if they're on the moon and the gravity is weak or absent; or it's about what happens to the moon itself when the gravity is weak or absent as in when it's hypothetically somehow being moved far away from our sun/earth or the sun or the earth is missing; or even something more imaginative. It'd be better to make clear what's the cause, and it happens to what/whom.

Comment: While it might not be s duplicate,  I would have closed this for a lack of detail/context.  There's not enough explanation of the meaning the asker is trying to express, and no explanation of why a dictionary didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you intend the sentence to mean:

> Q: What is the **result** of the lack of a strong gravitational pull on the moon?
>   A: The absence of an atmosphere.
>
> Q: What is the **effect** of the lack of a strong gravitational pull on the moon?
>   A: An astronaut weighs much less than on Earth and can move fast despite their heavy gear.